# Why doesn't this PHP PDO snippet work?

Tags: php, pdo

Why doesn't this PHP PDO snippet work?

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
$STH->bindParam(':fftb', $fftb);  
$STH->bindParam(':st', $st);  
$STH->bindParam(':la', $la);
$STH->bindParam(':cf', $cf);  
$STH->bindParam(':total', $total);  
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (fftb, st, la, cf, total) VALUES (:fftb, :st, :la, :cf, :total)"); 
$STH->execute();
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Where is $STH initialized? If $STH is not initialized properly, you can't invoke a method like bindParam etc. on it, as it does not contain an object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you are trying to `bind` parameters to a statement before you create the statement. First `prepare()`, then `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the corrected code below:

```
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (fftb, st, la, cf, total) VALUES (:fftb, :st, :la, :cf, :total)"); 
$STH->bindParam(':fftb', $fftb);  
$STH->bindParam(':st', $st);  
$STH->bindParam(':la', $la);
$STH->bindParam(':cf', $cf);  
$STH->bindParam(':total', $total);

$STH->execute();
```